# min average of mutiple array segments

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Given an array A I want to find the first index of a segment where the average of the chosen segment is the minimum among other segments.

```
Example: A = {1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
segment (1,2) = {1,1} ==> avg = 1+1/2 = 1
segment (1,3) = {1,1,3} ==> avg = 1+1+3/3 = 1.6
etc.. 
________________________________________________
input: {1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
output: 1
```

Explanation: the min avg is `1` hence the output should be the first index of that segment (1,2) which is: `1` in this case.

My current code looks like this:

```
int getIndex(vector<int> A) 
{
    if (A.size() <= 2) return 0; /*if array is a single segment then index:0 is the answer.*/

    vector<int> psums; psums.push_back(A[0]);

    for(size_t i =1; i< A.size(); i++)
    {
        psums.push_back(psums[i-1] + A[i]);
    }

    float min = 1111111111; /*assuming this is a max possible numb*/
    int index;
    float avg;

    for(size_t i =1; i< psums.size(); i++)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            avg = (float)((psums[i] - psums[j]) / (i-j+1));
            if (min > std::min(min, avg))
            {
                min = std::min(min, avg);
                index = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

This code returns incorrect value. Thoughts?

Comment: "This code returns incorrect value." How is it incorrect? Is it consistent (same input results in same value)? Is it at least a valid index into your vector?

Comment: `psums[i] - psums[j]` when calculating averages, summation is usually the first step.

Comment: You should learn to use debugger

Comment: Definitely..! "Drop" user is right.. You have to learn using debugger. It will be helpfull for you. And in my opinion, the easiest way for solving problem..

Comment: @Drop Debuggers do not solve logical issues with the code.

Comment: Ok, but I even think the problem is not fully specified. If I want to get the beginning of the segment with minimum average among all possible segments, I would simply use `std::distance(A.begin(),std::min_element(A.begin(),A.end()));`. This gives you the minimum element `j`, which by definition also provides the minimum range `(j,j)`. If the segment must be at least of length two, I would similarly search for the smallest sum of consecutive elements. Is that what you want... ? Please specify.

Comment: @AK_ that's exactly what they are for!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have some time, so here is the code you are hopefully looking for (and hopefully it compiles as well -- I have no chance to test that *before* I posted it, so give me a few minutes to check afterwards -- ok, compiles now with gcc-4.7.2):

```
#include<vector>
#include<tuple>
#include<functional>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include <numeric> 

size_t getIndex(const std::vector<int>& A) //pass by const ref instead of by value!

{
    size_t n=A.size();
    //define vector to store the averages and bounds
    std::vector<std::tuple<size_t, size_t, double> > store;

    for(size_t iend=0;iend<n;++iend)
        for(size_t ibegin=0;ibegin<iend;++ibegin)  //changed from <= to < as segments need to have length >=2
        {
             //compute average: sum all elements from ibegin to iend to 0.0, cast to double and divide by the number of elements
             double average=static_cast<double>(std::accumulate(A.begin()+ibegin, A.begin()+iend,0.0))/(iend-ibegin+1);

             //store the result with bounds
             store.push_back(std::make_tuple(ibegin,iend,average));
        }

    //define lambda which compares the tuple according to the third component
    auto compare_third_element=[](const std::tuple<size_t,size_t,double> &t1, const std::tuple<size_t,size_t,double> &t2){return std::get<2>(t1)<std::get<2>(t2);};

    //now find the iterator to the minimum element
    auto it=std::min_element(store.begin(),store.end(),compare_third_element);

    //print range
    //std::cout<<"("<<std::get<0>(*it)<<","<<std::get<1>(*it)<<")"<<std::endl;
    return std::get<0>(*it);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> A={1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    std::cout << getIndex(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Caution: there might be more than a single segment which yields the minimum average. For the example above, the function prints the segment `(0,0)` on the screen, since it contains the minimum element `1`. If you want to obtain the range you are looking for, either use `std::nth_element` to access the next entries, or change the comparison function (e.g. give longer tuples a higher priority).

Comment: Great - care to give a walkthrough the code? Is it safe to say this is O(N^2) ?

Comment: Also please note that segments cannot be one element. (1,1) or (0,0). General case:(x,y) x<y

Comment: Ok, if segments need to have length >=2, then change `for(size_t ibegin=0;ibegin<=iend;++ibegin)` to `for(size_t ibegin=0;ibegin<iend;++ibegin)` (note the `<` instead of `<=`). Regarding the walkthrough, I've added some comments to the code. Regarding O(N^2): the problem in my comment to your question remains: without further constraints, there is no need not to choose the two smallest consecutive elements -- this leads to complexity O(N).

Comment: thanks agian! give me sometime I will go through it and eventually mark it as answered later

Comment: Just checked your code. There is something wrong with it. It is not returning the correct val in the case of A = { 4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 5, 8 } - expected output 1. Actual output (4,5) --> 5

Comment: you seem to have fixed the wrog behavior, do you? (there stood `std::get<1>` instead of `std::get<0>`)

Comment: yep but still the algorithm is not returning the correct answer. I am thinking about some other algorithm. 

This is what I have in mind:
Sort the array, calculate the average of the very first elements as long as you have a min(avg) continue adding adjacent elements

example:
{ 1, 43, 56, 78 ,2 ,4}
sorted: {1, 2, 4, 43, 56, 78}
min avg is between {1,2} = 1.5
even by adding {1,2,4} = 1.7 so we go back to the previous result and echo the index of {1}

==== we will have O(nLogn) (using quicksort)

Answer (score 0):

Both `(psums[i] - psums[j])` and `(i-j+1)` are integers. The division between them is the so called, incomplete division thus you get just the whole part, of the result. Cast one of the elements to float or double, like this:

```
(float)(psums[i] - psums[j])/(i-j+1)
```

The type of division in `a/b` depend on the type of `a` and `b` **not the variable you put the result in!**

*Note:* `std::min(min, avg)` is not required, instead of that just use: `avg`

*Edit:* `psum[i]-psum[j]=A[i]+A[i-1]+...+A[j+1]` becouse `psum[i]=A[0]+A[1]+A[2]+..+A[i]` so 
the `avg`-line should look like this:

```
avg=(float)(psums[i] - psums[j] + A[j])/(i-j+1)
```

Comment: Ok I fixed this in the code but I still get wrong answer. Also please explain more your list line I didn't quite get what you mean?

Comment: `psum[i]-psum[j]=A[i]+A[i-1]+...+A[j+1]` becouse `psum[i]=A[0]+A[1]+A[2]+..+A[i]`